# error (Unreachable Code) in calling variable

Tags: java, unreachable-code

I'm trying to make a program that lets  the user to input 10 integers, and then calculate the average of that integers. I got `Unreachable code` error in `System.out.println("average : " + average);` line.

I already try to make a new class and call the method to my main method but it seems not a simple way to do that (and also there's still some error that make me more confuse). So I guess I can make a simple program like this. But i'm stuck figuring out what's wrong with the code. Here's the code.

```
package nomer15;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class averag {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter 10 integers : ");

        double average;
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numbers[] = new int[10];
        for(int i = 0; 1 < 10; i++){
            numbers[i] = sc.nextInt();

            sum = sum + numbers[i];

            average = sum/10;

        }

        System.out.println("average : " + average);  // (Unreachable code error)

    }

}
```

Can you figure out what I did wrong? Thank you.

Comment: `1 < 10` in the for loop conditional makes the loop run forever. I suspect you meant to put `i < 10`.

Comment: lol sorry I didnt realize that! IT works! but I have to initialize the `average` Thank you.

Comment: @JonnyHenly very well spotted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to your loop test being incorrect (`1` is always less than `10`), you should calculate the average after the loop. And you shouldn't use integer math. Finally, I would prefer `numbers.length` to the *magic* `10`. Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = new int[10];
    System.out.printf("Enter %d integers : ", numbers.length);
    int sum = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        sum += (numbers[i] = sc.nextInt());
    }
    double average = sum / (double) numbers.length;
    System.out.println("average : " + average);
}
```

Comment: this code totally better than mine. Btw why we need `numbers.length`? and can you please explain what this line means? `sum += (numbers[i] = sc.nextInt());`

Comment: I would prefer `numbers.length` because this way you change `new int[10]` to `new int[20]` or `new int[5]` and the code still works. Assign `sc.nextInt()` to  `numbers[i]` add that same value to `sum`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your code looking at the line below:

```
 for(int i = 0; 1 < 10; i++)
```

You probably meant the code should be:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //replace 1 with i
```

Comment: In the future, consider using the typo close reason.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the failure in `for(int i = 0; 1 < 10; i++)` I didnt realize  that I put 1 instead of `i` there.
Now it works like a charm after I initialize `average`